# Azure Data Factory - Issue with Date converting to a 5 digit number once it hits the sink

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm pulling in a file(JSON) from MongoDb and converting it into a table. I'm currently flattening the file and then doing a derived column transformation to convert the dates to date type. When I preview the data it shows it as a date. When I pull it into the sink and check the input and output it shows it as a date. Yet when I preview the data in the sink it converts it to "Long" and it's a 5 digit number. I can't seem to find how or why this is happening.

I tried taking the 5 digit long number and checking it in Excel and instead of giving me the date that was in 2018 it gives a date in 1948. So I'm not sure if there is a way to transform this back in SQL or PowerBI... but I'm at a loss since I've pulled dates from this data base with other objects and the date didn't do this with the exact same steps.

I've also tried manually mapping inside the sink to make sure it's the date selected and it still transforms to the 5 digit number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

[[[[Pictures of transformation and sink images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k60Kd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgoGf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIQDB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQixt.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Read: [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and make use of block quotes \`\`\`like this\`\`\`.

Comment: @aneroid I mean... there isn't any code... It's all visuals... but okay... downvote me for that. cool

Comment: Have you checked sink schema?

Comment: Hey @PratikLad, I have it currently set to allow schema drift I don't have validate schema checked if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: @WilliamAllen What do you mean there's no code? _"I'm pulling in a file(JSON)"_ - so show what that file looks like. _"I'm currently flattening the file"_ - so what's the format of the flattened file?

Answer (score 0):

While I can't figure out why it's converting the date to a number I did find a way to solve this for my use case. In sql server I was able to figure out the reference date used to supply the number is not 1/1/1900 like most systems it seems ADF uses the reference date of 1/1/1970. So I simply built a query to reference this date and was able to fix it.

Hope this helps someone down the road and saves them the hours I spent trying to find a solution.